# Accionar botón web con un icono SVG no funciona "correctamente" al clicar sobre el icono

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba implementando un botón con un icono SVG, como el de la imagen, pero sin borde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Capturo la ID del botón al hacer clic para almacenar las pulsaciones, incrementándose el número. Todo normal.

Al pulsar el botón recojo la ID a partir del *target*, pero no funcionaba correctamente si se pulsaba sobre el área del SVG. Si se acciona el botón y se recoge el evento, pero el *target* no tiene la ID del botón. Entonces el siguiente código sólo funciona si se pulsa el botón, pero no sobre el corazón:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        button {
            background: transparent;
        }
        button,
        main {
            align-items     : center;
            display         : flex;
            justify-content : space-between;
        }
        main {
            border  : 1px solid grey;
            margin  : 5% auto;
            padding : 1rem;
            width   : 320px;
        }
        svg {
            fill: none;
            stroke: rgb(212, 0, 89);
        }

        .btn {
            padding : .5rem;
            position: relative;
            z-index : 99999;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>

        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>

        <button class="btn" id="btn">
            5
            <svg viewBox="0 0 21 21" height="18" width="26" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path
                    d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z" />
            </svg>
        </button>
    </main>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            const buttonId = event.target.id;

            console.log('clicked button wit ID: ' + buttonId);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al pulsar el botón fuera del icono, la traza es:

```
clicked button wit ID: btn
```

Al pulsar el botón sobre el icono, la traza es:

```
clicked button wit ID:
```

La ID del botón que se esperaba recoger es `btn`.

***Nota:** mismo comportamiento en Chromium y Firefox.*

**¿Por qué ocurre esto?**

#### Solución

El código funciona si sustituyo el script por el siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const buttonId = event.target.id ? event.target.id : event.currentTarget.id;

    console.log('clicked button wit ID: ' + buttonId);
});
```

> Editado

Este código funciona porque el icono *svg* no tiene una ID propia, en caso contrario volvería a darse el mismo problema (ver ternaria). Una solución mejor sería:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const buttonId = event.currentTarget.id;

    console.log('clicked button wit ID: ' + buttonId);
});
```

El código del ejemplo que puse es bastante tonto, uso la id de un elemento para añadirle un *listener* y trato de recuperar su id cuando se pulsa. Lo cree a efectos de poder reproducir el problema.

La pregunta se refiere a ¿por qué se produce ese comportamiento en elementos anidados, clicar sobre ellos activa el botón, pero al tiempo no se recoge la ID del botón?. Se que planteo un problema y una solución funcional, puedo llegar a soluciones sin entender el porque de los problemas, pero es que me gusta saber por que ocurren las cosas.

Comment: probá con `svg.icon-inline { pointer-events: none; }` ó `event.currentTarget` el svg está sin id y es el que recibe el click, el current sería el que tiene el listener. MDN lo explica mejor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Nonono, la solución no se pone en la pregunta. Por favor, pon una respuesta y márcala aceptada

Comment: @Alfabravo según entiendo la pregunta es "¿Por qué ocurre esto?" habría que transcribir/traducir e interpretar el doc de MDN acerca del target y del currentTarget, en ciertos casos uno no querría anular los pointer events y permitir el bubbling diferenciando entre ambos

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¿Ah? No sé, yo no me refiero a ningún detalle técnico. Quien pregunta puso "**Solución:** el código funciona si xyz" y así no funciona StackOverflow. Las respuestas no van dentro de la pregunta, es todo

Comment: meh, "solución" != "respuesta"

Comment: @aloMalbarez correcto, quería saber el porque de tener que usar *target* normalmente, y *currentTarget* en el caso del elemento "anidado".

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres solucionar con CSS puedes agregar **pointer-events: none** en tu clase **.svg**  y quedaría resulto.